# typo3 viewhelper call method inside viewhelper class

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

How can I call a (own written ) method inside a viewhelper?

public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext) {

$this->myMethod();

I guess it won't work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each ViewHelper is a standalone class, if that method `myMethod()` is declared within this class, make it static `private static function myMethod(){...}` and call as `self::myMethod();`.